# Execute a value once in the for loop

Tags: php

In array list  [hide] =>1 having 2 times, how to execute a [hide] =>1 only one time in for loop . how to check current array with all previous value and [hide] =>1 execute once in the for loop

need to execute [id] =>4  , no need to execute a  [id] => 2  in for loop

Array

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [id] => 6 [hide] => 0  ) 
    [1] => Array ( [id] => 5  [hide] => 0 )
    [2] => Array ( [id] => 4  [hide] => 1 )
    [3] => Array ( [id] => 3  [hide] => 0  )
    [4] => Array ( [id] => 2 [hide] => 1  )
)
```

Comment: What do you mean "execute a array value"? Please reformulate, this overall doesn't make much sense (at least to me).

Comment: try using `array_filter()` to obtain the array subset to performs the actions you want. tbh I'm really not sure what you want

Comment: Just use a simple boolean flag …?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..... You can use this function for any depth of the associated array.

```
 function is_in_array($array, $key, $key_value){
    $within_array = 'no';
    foreach( $array as $k=>$v ){
      if( is_array($v) ){
          $within_array = is_in_array($v, $key, $key_value);
          if( $within_array == 'yes' ){
              break;
         }
      } else {
             if( $v == $key_value && $k == $key ){
                     $within_array = 'yes';
                     break;
             }
        }
     }
      return $within_array;
   }
   print_r(is_in_array($yourarray, 'hide', '1'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want the item with the greatest ID :

```
// get only the items with 'hide' = 1
$hidden = array_filter($array, function($item){return $item['hide'] == 1;});

// order the array to have the items with the greatest ID first
usort($hidden, function($a, $b){
    return $b['id'] - $a['id'] ;
});

// print the item with the max id 
print_r($hidden[0]);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for($i = 0; $i<count($array); $i++){

  if($array[$i] == 4){
       print_r($array[4]);
   }
}
```

Comment: My above code is a sample  i having a dynamic array in for loop ur answer is not  suits for that

Comment: Please, add some description.